# after paypal transaction get data with out click continue button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on PayPal and getting one problem here

if I am not clicking on continue button with in 10 seconds

then i get blank post array which returns from the PayPal other wise i am getting whole array with transaction id from PayPal.

[image: Paypal]

so here I want to get post array which returns from the PayPal without clicking continue button.

Comment: i am passing value to paypal in hidden fields